# Determinant complexity

Tags: arithmetic-circuits

The best circuit known for determinants of size $n \times n$ have size $n^{O(log(n))}$. Is there any evidence either way that this can be brought to fully polynomial size or not? I am aware of Raz's work that this is lower bound for multilinear circuits.

Comment: The best known arithmetic circuit for $n \times n$ determinant has size $\tilde{O}(n^{\omega})$ (where $\omega < 2.373$ is the matrix multiplication exponent)

Comment: Maybe the question was meant to be about formula size rather than circuit size? Best known formula size for the determinant is quasipolynomial. But improving this to polynomial or proving a matching lower bound is a well-known open question.